# Spring OAuth + JWT -- /oauth/token

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to configure my spring application to use JWT using https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth.  I've exposed a bean for `ConsumerTokenServices` backed by a `JwtTokenStore`, but hitting `/oauth/token` doesn't give me a JWT.

`` $ curl localhost:8643/contextpath/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials -u user:password`
{"access_token":"a78a6225-78d5-4cb8-9393-6c0b567a6f24","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":5684,"scope":"read write"}% ``

I know that the `TokenStore` is being used, because hitting `check_token` produces an error, where it didn't before.

`$ curl https://localhost:8643/context/oauth/check_token?token=a78a6225-78d5-4cb8-9393-6c0b567a6f24
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Cannot convert access token to JSON"}%`

How do I make my `TokenEndpoint` spit back a JWT?

Comment: Did you try making a sample app with Spring Boot 1.3? It does come with auto support for OAuth2, see http://spring.io/blog/2015/11/16/spring-boot-1-3-0-released. I would try to build a sample app and then to look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/OAuth2AutoConfiguration.java  and https://github.com/dynamind/spring-boot-security-oauth2-minimal. Another good blog series is https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v

Comment: See https://github.com/dynamind/spring-boot-security-oauth2-minimal

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I ended up not using Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use JwtAccessTokenConverter provided by spring and then properly  configured.
Here is an example:

```
public class YourTokenEnhancer extends JwtAccessTokenConverter {

//you can autowire sth for you logic

@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken,
                                 OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    DefaultOAuth2AccessToken customAccessToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(accessToken);

    OAuth2AccessToken enhancedToken = super.enhance(customAccessToken, authentication);
    return enhancedToken;
}
```

And the configuration is:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableAuthorizationServer
 public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
 //other config...
 @Bean
 public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
    JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new YourTokenEnhancer();
    converter.setSigningKey("secret");
    return converter;
 }

 @Override
 public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .tokenStore(redisTokenStore())
            .tokenServices(authorizationServerTokenServices())
            .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())//configure it here
            ;
 }
}
```